# Timestamp lost when copying file to samba share from another Linux box

Tags: ubuntu, samba, timestamps

I've got a samba share on an Ubuntu 20.04 box. When I copy a file to the share from a Windows box the timestamp is maintained, but when I do the same thing from another Ubuntu 20.04 box, the timestamp is lost.

The relevant section of the smb.conf file on the share server is currently:

```
[test]
    comment = test share
    path = /testing
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
    force user = user1
    dos filetimes = yes
```

I've tried with and with out the **force user** and **dos filetimes** commands.

On the Ubuntu client I'm mounting the share with:

```
sudo mount //192.168.1.2/test /testing -o credentials=/home/user1/.cifs,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.1.1
```

In researching the problem I've read several places that setting the uid/gid in the mount command is the key, but that's not solving the problem.